# get_posts() in secondary sidebar messes up content in primary sidebar

Tags: sidebar, get-posts

I use get_posts() to generate a menu of posts having the current page as the parent. This causes the post_id to be set to the first such post, instead of the original page's post_id. I.e. I want Wordpress to continue as if nothing happened after the query.

This is the code I use in sidebar.php:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'offset'           => 0,
'category'         => '',
'orderby'          => 'title',
'order'            => 'ASC',
'include'          => '',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => '',
'post_type'        => $slug,
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$pt=get_the_title();
$posts=get_posts($args);
//loop children custom posts.
if ($posts) {
    echo '<div class="generated-menu">';
    echo '<ul class="left-navigation"><li class="active"><a href="/'.$slug.'">'.$m.'</a>';
    // Start the Loop.
    foreach ($posts as $p) {

        $t=get_the_title($p->ID);
        $l=get_permalink($p->ID);
        $a='';if ($t==$pt) $a=' class="active"';
        echo '<ul><li'.$a.'>';
        echo '<a href="'.$l.'">'.$t.'</a>';
        echo '</li></ul>';

    }   //foreach
    echo '</li></ul></div>';
}   //if has posts
```

All available information says get_posts() doesn't affect anything. Well, that's confirmed to be a lie, unless you can spot an error in my code.

If I comment out the single line `$posts=get_posts($args);`, main content is OK.

I have tried using wp_reset_postdata(), no difference.

Thankful for any help by the pros here :)

Comment: This looks ok. Are you confident that this is the portion of code that causes ID to change? Is it changed if you dump it _right after_ this?

Comment: possibly the use of `$posts` might be interfering; try to change that to something else like `$menu_posts` or similar, and try what @Shellbot suggested.

Comment: If I comment out the single line $posts=get_posts($args);, main content is OK.

Comment: @Michael, you spotted the name conflict! If I refrain from using $posts as variable name, it works. Add it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll put that as an answer so the topic can be marked as solved (just for the forum staistics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of `$posts` might be interfering; try to change that to something else like `$menu_posts` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the query after your if statement.

`<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

See if that does the trick.

Comment: No, I had that.